# How do you make a Hapi.JS plugin/module?

Tags: node.js, plugins, module, hapi.js

I'm new to both *Node* and *Hapi.js*, but not to programming.

I've made a few simple *Hapi.js* servers, just for testing out *Joi* and other plugins.

I'm now trying to understand how best to package up chunks of functionality in a Hapi way, so we can re-use them in future projects and potentially share them with the world!

Are there any good resources for learning this available?

**EDIT:**
I've found a few good resources, but non which go into deep details about the plugin system.

- https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1489 - Getting Started Tutorial Contest
- https://github.com/otodockal/hapi-tutorial - Entry in above contest, with a section on plugins

Answer (score 7):

I've made a sample project which groups functionality into plugins which might be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/johnbrett/hapi-level-sample

If you're looking at sharing functionality between plugins, look at the usage of plugin.expose, plugin.depend.

If you have any questions on it, you can raise an issue on the github project.

The latest hapijs.com website has a good intro as well: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/plugins

Answer (score 2):

For some additional detail about hapi plugins (and hapi in general), see the following:

- [Developing a hapi Edge: A Rich Node.JS Framework for Apps and Services](http://bleedingedgepress.com/developing-a-hapi-edge/) - This book is available now ([also from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B013CWI3MY)), and has a chapter on how to create a plugin in hapi.
- Matt Harrison's upcoming [hapi.js in Action](http://www.manning.com/harrison/) - This book is available currently in "MEAP" (Manning Early Access Program), and will soon (?) have a chapter available on plugins ("Building modular applications with Plugins").
- [hapi plugin search engine](https://hapi-plugins.com/)
- [Getting Started with hapi.js](https://gettingstartedwithhapijs.com) by John Brett also has a chapter on creating and using plugins.

***Edit 2015-10-04:*** The chapter "Building modular applications with Plugins" in Matt Harrison's above mentioned book is now available in the MEAP edition.